# Regex: searching for HTML tags in the text

Tags: python, regex, url, findall

I am very new to REGEX and HTML in particular. I know that BeautifulSoup is a way to deal with HTML but would like to try regex

I need to search the text for HTML tags (I use findall). I tried multiple scenarios and examples in Stackoverflow but only got [] (empty string). Here is what I tried:

```
#reHTML = r'(?:<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\1>)'
#reHTML = r'\<p>(.*?)\</p>'
#reHTML = r'<p>(.*?)\</p>'
#reHTML = r'<raw[^>]*?>(.*?)</raw>'

reHTML = r'<p>(.*?)</p>'

#reHTML = r'<.*?>'
```

and:

```
rHTML = re.compile(reHTML, re.VERBOSE)

HTMLpara = rHTML.findall('http://pythonprogramming.net/parse-website-using- regular-expressions-urllib/', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Obviously, I am missing something. Please, help

Comment: Do you mean to search the contents of the webpage? Right now you are just searching the URL.

Comment: @digitaLink - HTML Tags rather than a full content. I am sure I messed up. Very new to Regex:)

Comment: Use an html parser like http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ not a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood [regex.findall(string[, pos[, endpos]])](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html?highlight=findall#re.regex.findall)

`HTMLpara = rHTML.findall('http://pythonprogramming.net/parse-website-using- regular-expressions-urllib/', re.IGNORECASE)`
means you will match the `rHTML` pattern with the string(`"http://pythonprogramming.net/parse-website-using- regular-expressions-urllib/"`),so you will get `[]`

You'd better request the URL to get data, then call findall to analyze the result string, as [below](http://pythonprogramming.net/parse-website-using-regular-expressions-urllib/).

```
import urllib.request
import re

url = 'http://pythonprogramming.net/parse-website-using-regular-expressions-urllib/'

req = urllib.request.Request(url)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()
paragraphs = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>',str(respData))
```

Comment: could you clarify, please what do you mean by "request the URL"? Sorry, for a silly question but regex is very new to me

Comment: @Toly My mean is you should get the html page data through url,then regex the data. `findall` use the first parameter as a string, it doesn't get the data through your url, do your code means you want match patterns witch the url string.

Comment: I figured that with the help of some good people here. It is a great point! I am just a greeny and am learning:)

Answer (score 0):

This will read in a webpage and find any instances of `<html>` or `</html>`. Is this the solution you are looking for?

```
import re
import urllib2
url = "http://stackoverflow.com"
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
file = f.read()
p = re.compile("<html>|</html>")
instances = p.findall(file)
print instances
```

Output:

```
['<html>', '</html>']
```

I think your problem was you were trying to search the URL string for HTML tags instead of actually loading the webpage and searching it.

Comment: possibly:) HTML is not my area but need to learn to work with text that may have everything in it. I actually need two regexs: one for URL and one for tags. I just started with tags here. In your example, however you have html rather than http or https (need both). Do I miss something again?:)

Comment: If you need help generating regex expressions that will create matches for your text this site is really good: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: I will try. Thank you

Comment: it only prints ['<html>', '</html>']. Is something missing?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: html tags only. Thank you

Comment: print " ".join(str(instances) for e in instances)